# People close to me by geolocation

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, geolocation

I have a user base, and with these I get the location with html5. Pro users would like to show the users who are close to him within 10 km .. How can I do this?

What data do I need to save, and how to calculate? I'm completely lost

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Send user locations back to the server.

Step 2: Calculate the distance of the target user from all other users.

Step 3: Find the closest users from the target user based on calculated distance.

Step 4: Send this data to target user.

Each step especially 2 and 3 is bit heavy if you want to do in optimized way. That is for another day/question :).